# Determining the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(n)z^n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

so I wanted to determine the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(n)z^n$.
I tried using Cauchy-Hadamard but I couldn't determine the $\limsup$.
So is there maybe another way or a way to determine the lim sup ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :** Show and use the two following facts.

1. $(\cos(n))$ is bounded, so the radius of convergence is greater or equal to $1$.
2. The series diverges for $z=1$, so the radius is less or equal to $1$.

Comment: (1) implies that the radius of convergence is at least $1$ because of absolute convergence and the geometric series, right?

Comment: why does the divergence at z=1 imply the radius is less or equal to 1

Comment: @AlannRosas Yes, you are right

Comment: @Dan Because if the radius was strictly greater than $1$, then the point $z=1$ would lie strictly inside the disk of convergence, and hence the series would converge at $z=1$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe ok got it and why does the fact that cos is bounded imply that the radius of convergence is greater or equal to 1 ? 
we have that it is smaller or equal to 1 and therefore  the absolute value of $\cos(n)z^n$ is smaller or equal to the absolute value of $z^n$ and this converges for the absolute value of z smaller than 1

Comment: maybe it would be easier to show that if $a_n$ is a bounded sequence but $a_n$ doesn't converge to zero, then the radius of convergence of $\sum a_nz^n$ is $1$ as that eliminates the clutter from the specific case here ( by comparison with $\sum M|z^n|$ shows the radius is at least $1$ since we have absolute convergence for $|z|<r<1$ for all $r<1$; the fact that $a_n$ doesn't converge to zero shows that $\sum a_n$ is not convergent so the series doesn;t converge at $1$ hence the radius must be $1$)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe how do i show that it diverges for $z=1$ every attempt on my side failed so far

Comment: Note that $\cos 2n=2\cos^2n-1$ so if $\cos n$ is close to zero, $\cos 2n$ is close to $-1$ so $\cos n$ cannot converge to zero, so $\sum \cos n$ cannot converge

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{in} z^n= \frac{1}{1-e^iz}$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{in} z^n= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\cos(n)+i\sin(n)) z^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(n) z^n +i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(n)z^n.$$
That is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \cos(n) z^n=Re(\frac{1}{1-e^iz})=\frac{1-z\cos(1)}{z^2-2\cos(1)z+1}.$$
This function has singularities in $z_{\pm}=\cos(1)\pm\sqrt{\frac{\cos(2)-1}{2}}$, and $|z_{\pm}|=1$, so the radius must be equal $1$.